# Oracle Hints for Date and Time

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which contains a column with date and time, and the user of the table wants to be able to select off the latest row. Now, this table has quite large of rows, and I am not talking a few hundred thousands.

The simplest way would be to order by descending, but with such a large number of rows, this isn't great performance wise. The column is index, but I was wondering if there is a oracle hint that could be put into the select to run the query much faster.

Does anyone have any experience on selecting rows based on the latest date and time with such a large table?

Comment: Do you still use (15 years old) Oracle 10g? In Oracle 12.1 you can use the ROW LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

10g is, as @Wernfried said, a little bit outdated. So what? I use it too (for some applications). As you can't change that, let's try to find a way to make it *faster*. Have a look at this option, see if it helps.

Sample table which mimics "your table", as a copy of Scott's EMP table. Index the *date* column (as you have it):

```
SQL> create table your_table as select * From emp;

Table created.

SQL> create index i1 on your_table (hiredate);

Index created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate from your_table order by hiredate desc;

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ----------
      7876 ADAMS      12.01.1983
      7788 SCOTT      09.12.1982
      7934 MILLER     23.01.1982
      7902 FORD       03.12.1981
      7900 JAMES      03.12.1981
      7839 KING       17.11.1981
      7654 MARTIN     28.09.1981
      7844 TURNER     08.09.1981
      7782 CLARK      09.06.1981
      7698 BLAKE      01.05.1981
      7566 JONES      02.04.1981
      7521 WARD       22.02.1981
      7499 ALLEN      20.02.1981
      7369 SMITH      17.12.1980

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, the *idea* itself: create a new table which will contain only one row - `hiredate` which is currently MAX in your table:

```
SQL> create table maxdat (maxdat date);

Table created.

SQL> -- Initial insert
SQL> insert into maxdat (maxdat) select max(hiredate) from your_table;

1 row created.

SQL> select * From maxdat;

MAXDAT
----------
12.01.1983

SQL>
```

In order to maintain the `maxdat` table, create a database trigger - it'll replace current `MAXDAT` column value if newly added (or updated) `hiredate` in your table is larger than `MAXDAT`:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_aiu_yourt
  2    after insert or update on your_table
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_maxdat maxdat.maxdat%type;
  6  begin
  7    merge into maxdat m
  8      using (select :new.hiredate as hiredate from dual) x
  9      on (1 = 1)
 10    when matched then update set
 11      m.maxdat = x.hiredate
 12    where x.hiredate > m.maxdat;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select * from maxdat;

MAXDAT
----------
12.01.1983

SQL>
```

Let's force `MAXDAT` change (employee FORD will now have the highest `hiredate` column value):

```
SQL> update your_table set hiredate = date '1984-01-01' where ename = 'FORD';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From maxdat;

MAXDAT
----------
01.01.1984

SQL>
```

Finally, your query, which now won't have to scan the whole huge table (actually, index), but a one-row table: `maxdat`:

```
SQL> select y.empno, y.ename, y.job, y.sal, y.hiredate
  2  from your_table y cross join maxdat m
  3  where y.hiredate = m.maxdat;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL HIREDATE
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000 01.01.1984

SQL>
```

As `hiredate` column is indexed and you know the `maxdat` value, this *might* be quite fast.

Possible drawback: if there are numerous concurrent inserts/updates into `your_table`, trigger might slow things down but - there ain't no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I do have a drawback where the table will be having rows inserted by the thousands very from an automated service. So I can see the trigger getting in the way.

Comment: You're welcome. Let's hope that someone else gets a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - no specific experience with date/time columns in large tables.

You could try:

- the FIRST_ROWS hint ([Oracle 10g docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#4942)),
- to create an index, which includes all relevant columns to save the trip to the actual rows, or
- to partition the table by date.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.